# Differentiating $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}|x-y_i|^2$ where $y_1,...,y_N\in \Bbb{R}^n$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $y_1,...,y_N\in \Bbb{R}^n$ and let $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}|x-y_i|^2$. I need to show that $f$ has a minimum. I try to differentiate but I am having troubles doing so. First of all, does $|x-y_i|$ stand for norm? Because I know another sign for that and not sure about that specifically. Even if it is, I am confused as for how to differentiate. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: We have $|x-y|^2 = (x-y)\cdot (x-y) = \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - y_k)^2$ where $x_k$ is the $k$'th component of $x$.

Comment: btw you don't need derivatives to show that $f$ has a minimum. Note that $f$ is contiunous. Show that the minimum must be inside some bounded region and use properties of continuous functions.

Comment: You are correct, which is why I thought to edit my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By expanding $f$ and then re-factorizing it in a slightly different form we find

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N x^2 - 2x\cdot y_i + y_i^2 = N[x^2 - 2x\cdot \overline{y} + Y] = N(x-\overline{y})^2 + N[Y - \overline{y}^2]$$

where $\overline{y} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N y_i}{N}$ and $Y = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2}{N}$. From this last form, remember that $x^2 \geq 0$, it is clear that $x = \overline{y}$ minimizes $f$.

One can also obtain this by differentiation. Note that $x^2 \equiv \sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2$ so $\frac{\partial x^2}{\partial x_k} = 2x_k$. This gives

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} = \sum_{i=1}^N2(x-y_i)_k = 2N(x-\overline{y})_k$$

so $\nabla f = 0$ if $x = \overline{y}$. One can then proceed to show that this is a true minimum.

Comment: @Surb Yes, indeed it is. Thanks for spotting it!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$f(x) = f(\bar y) + n \,|x-\bar y|^2$$